# Running selenium on a headless EC2 machine?

Tags: ruby, selenium, amazon-ec2, headless

I have a headless EC2 M1.Small instance running Ubuntu.  I have been trying to use it to run a selenium test coded in Ruby.  I am running selenium server 2.0b3 (the latest).

i have enabled XVFB:

> *$ sudo startx -- which Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &
>   [1] 1119*
>
> $ DISPLAY=:1 java -jar Automation/ruby-selenium-framework/selenium-server-1.0.3/selenium-server.jar > /tmp/selenium_log.log &
>   [2] 1245

And then run my code:

```
$ ./BTRuby.rb coverage_
```

I get the following output to the selenium log:

```
14:11:27.448 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, URL, , ] on session null
14:11:27.448 INFO - creating new remote session
14:11:27.448 INFO - Allocated session 4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308 for URL, launching...
14:11:27.488 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
14:11:30.709 INFO - Launching Firefox...
14:11:35.873 INFO - Got result: OK,4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308 on session 4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308
14:11:35.878 INFO - Command request: setTimeout[30000000, ] on session 4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308
14:11:35.937 INFO - Got result: OK on session 4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308
14:11:36.007 INFO - Command request: open[URL, ] on session 4b1395b136174ab798eddd6a59d8e308
```

Can anyone provide any help?  It just seems to hang at this last INFO line.

BTW, the URL variable is a valid URL that I have stripped out for purposes of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo startx -- which Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &

DISPLAY=:1 java -jar selenium-server-1.0.3/selenium-server.jar > /tmp/selenium_log.log &

was able to do the trick